# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on soapUI installation

Tags: java, installation, soapui

I'm trying to install [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) on my laptop and am getting the following error:

> Starting Installer ...
>   
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
>   
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Component
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon$2.run(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon.createNoPermsComponent(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon.access$000(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon$1.run(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.loadIcon(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallerUtil.reportException(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
>   
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.loadIcon(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallerUtil.reportException(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
>   
>         at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)

Not sure what's going on.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SoapUI is distributed with its own `JRE`. From the stacktrace it appears that the application cannot find the runtime jar (`rt.jar`). Its probably easier to download a new copy of the test tool to resolve this.

If the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable is that is set SoapUI uses the JRE installed at that location otherwise it uses its own copy. Its possible that `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to a JRE which has a corrupt runtime JAR file.

Try clearing this environmental variable or setting it to an another `JRE`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried a new copy of the soapUI installer, actually copied the version that worked quite well on my desktop.  Unfortunately it yielded the same error.  ...unless I'm mistaken in what you mean by the test tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java correctly installed on your system, just use the zip version.
You may need to set your JAVA_HOME variable if you continue to see the same error.
Zip versions for every platform are available [here](http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/latest-release.html).

Just extract the zip, and run bin/soapui.sh